# Change Hamming distance

Tags: python, hamming-distance

I want to find the way to change my hamming distance between strings with binary numbers by adding as few parts as possible. I'm supposed to use a sparse tree and depth first search but I don't really know how I will use this.

Comment: Can you add examples of expected input and output of the function you are trying to build? And explain what you actually tried

Comment: example of inputs is '1100010' ,'1001101', '1111111', '1111101', '1101001'  . And I want to add numbers to the strings which has a Hamming distance less than x (som integer). And I want to add as few numbers as possible.

Comment: Use the `Levenstein` library to calculate the hamming distance. Documentation: http://www.coli.uni-saarland.de/courses/LT1/2011/slides/Python-Levenshtein.html#Levenshtein-hamming and then loop through the string pairs character by character when the distance is lower than threshold and when the characters are the same you flip the bit of one string (1 to a 0 or a 0 to a 1) and recalculate the increased hamming distance against your threshold and flip more characters if the pair is still having low distance. Paste your code attempt and lets take it form there. Remember strings are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with this code. It calculate the hamming distance between each pair of strings in the list if binary strings. If the distance is less than a minimum threshold it modifies only one of the two strings until the minimum distance is reached. This is not quite right because modifying one string in the pair results in more modifications in one string so the better solution would to modify one string and then next time the other one. But you can fix that one if this looks like what you need.

```
import Levenshtein as lv

min_distance = 3
numbers = {'1100010' ,'1001101', '1111111', '1111101', '1101001'}

for number in numbers:
    other_numbers = numbers - {number}
    for other_number in other_numbers:
        distance = lv.hamming(number, other_number)
        backup_other_number = other_number
        while lv.hamming(number, other_number) < min_distance:
            for count, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(number, other_number)):
                if a == b:
                    other_number = ''.join([
                        n if c != count else str(int(a != '1'))
                        for c, n in enumerate(other_number)
                    ])
                if lv.hamming(number, other_number) >= min_distance:
                    break
        print 'Old pair: {0}, distance: {1}'.format(
            (number, backup_other_number),
            distance
        )
        print 'New pair: {0}, distance: {1}'.format(
            (number, other_number),
            lv.hamming(number, other_number)
        )
    print '=' * 80
```

Output:

```
(tmp)➜  ~  python hamming.py
Old pair: ('1001101', '1111101'), distance: 2
New pair: ('1001101', '0111101'), distance: 3
Old pair: ('1001101', '1111111'), distance: 3
New pair: ('1001101', '1111111'), distance: 3
Old pair: ('1001101', '1100010'), distance: 5
New pair: ('1001101', '1100010'), distance: 5
Old pair: ('1001101', '1101001'), distance: 2
New pair: ('1001101', '0101001'), distance: 3
================================================================================
Old pair: ('1111101', '1001101'), distance: 2
New pair: ('1111101', '0001101'), distance: 3
Old pair: ('1111101', '1111111'), distance: 1
New pair: ('1111101', '0011111'), distance: 3
Old pair: ('1111101', '1100010'), distance: 5
New pair: ('1111101', '1100010'), distance: 5
Old pair: ('1111101', '1101001'), distance: 2
New pair: ('1111101', '0101001'), distance: 3
================================================================================
Old pair: ('1111111', '1001101'), distance: 3
New pair: ('1111111', '1001101'), distance: 3
Old pair: ('1111111', '1111101'), distance: 1
New pair: ('1111111', '0011101'), distance: 3
Old pair: ('1111111', '1100010'), distance: 4
New pair: ('1111111', '1100010'), distance: 4
Old pair: ('1111111', '1101001'), distance: 3
New pair: ('1111111', '1101001'), distance: 3
================================================================================
Old pair: ('1100010', '1001101'), distance: 5
New pair: ('1100010', '1001101'), distance: 5
Old pair: ('1100010', '1111101'), distance: 5
New pair: ('1100010', '1111101'), distance: 5
Old pair: ('1100010', '1111111'), distance: 4
New pair: ('1100010', '1111111'), distance: 4
Old pair: ('1100010', '1101001'), distance: 3
New pair: ('1100010', '1101001'), distance: 3
================================================================================
Old pair: ('1101001', '1001101'), distance: 2
New pair: ('1101001', '0001101'), distance: 3
Old pair: ('1101001', '1111101'), distance: 2
New pair: ('1101001', '0111101'), distance: 3
Old pair: ('1101001', '1111111'), distance: 3
New pair: ('1101001', '1111111'), distance: 3
Old pair: ('1101001', '1100010'), distance: 3
New pair: ('1101001', '1100010'), distance: 3
================================================================================
(tmp)➜  ~  
(tmp)➜  ~  python hamming.py
Old pair: ('1001101', '1111101'), distance: 2
New pair: ('1001101', '0111101'), distance: 3
Old pair: ('1001101', '1111111'), distance: 3
New pair: ('1001101', '1111111'), distance: 3
Old pair: ('1001101', '1100010'), distance: 5
New pair: ('1001101', '1100010'), distance: 5
Old pair: ('1001101', '1101001'), distance: 2
New pair: ('1001101', '0101001'), distance: 3
================================================================================
Old pair: ('1111101', '1001101'), distance: 2
New pair: ('1111101', '0001101'), distance: 3
Old pair: ('1111101', '1111111'), distance: 1
New pair: ('1111101', '0011111'), distance: 3
Old pair: ('1111101', '1100010'), distance: 5
New pair: ('1111101', '1100010'), distance: 5
Old pair: ('1111101', '1101001'), distance: 2
New pair: ('1111101', '0101001'), distance: 3
================================================================================
Old pair: ('1111111', '1001101'), distance: 3
New pair: ('1111111', '1001101'), distance: 3
Old pair: ('1111111', '1111101'), distance: 1
New pair: ('1111111', '0011101'), distance: 3
Old pair: ('1111111', '1100010'), distance: 4
New pair: ('1111111', '1100010'), distance: 4
Old pair: ('1111111', '1101001'), distance: 3
New pair: ('1111111', '1101001'), distance: 3
================================================================================
Old pair: ('1100010', '1001101'), distance: 5
New pair: ('1100010', '1001101'), distance: 5
Old pair: ('1100010', '1111101'), distance: 5
New pair: ('1100010', '1111101'), distance: 5
Old pair: ('1100010', '1111111'), distance: 4
New pair: ('1100010', '1111111'), distance: 4
Old pair: ('1100010', '1101001'), distance: 3
New pair: ('1100010', '1101001'), distance: 3
================================================================================
Old pair: ('1101001', '1001101'), distance: 2
New pair: ('1101001', '0001101'), distance: 3
Old pair: ('1101001', '1111101'), distance: 2
New pair: ('1101001', '0111101'), distance: 3
Old pair: ('1101001', '1111111'), distance: 3
New pair: ('1101001', '1111111'), distance: 3
Old pair: ('1101001', '1100010'), distance: 3
New pair: ('1101001', '1100010'), distance: 3
================================================================================
```